# saving the changes in file

Tags: c++

**Ojective:** To open config file, look for a particular line which has tag and change its value

**Example:**

```
    config .txt    
    bla bla    
    bla bla   
    SYSTEM_A_EXTERNAL_IP=192.168.0.57  // need to change ip address    
    bla bla   
    bla bla
```

**What I have done so far:**  My code  open the file and look for the particular line which has tag  and change its value .

**Problem:** I failed to see those changes in the actual file. I am  aware that ofstream will write into line but if I  do ofstream instead of  ifstream  getline function gets an error.

**Code1:**

```
bool SetIpAddr(string & iAddr)    
{     
    bool check= false;    

    // Open  file    
    ifstream  iFile(IpConfigFile.c_str(), ios_base::out|ios::app | ios::binary);
    if(iFile.is_open())    
    {    
        check= true;    
    }          

    // Read content of ipconf file searching for the value of Head Id Name
    if(true == check)
    {
        string TargetName = SystemAIdValue + ExternalIpNamePostfix+ ValueAssignmentCharacter;
        string outbuf;
        while( !iFile.eof() )
        {
            getline(iFile, outbuf);    

            // find the matching string     
            if( 0 == outbuf.compare(0,TargetName.size(),TargetName) )
            {
            outbuf.erase(outbuf.begin()+TargetName.size(), outbuf.end());    
            outbuf.insert(0+TargetName.size(), iAddr);
                std::cout<< " after insertion  " << outbuf << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Close  (input) file
    if( iFile.is_open() )
    {
        iFile.close();
    }
    return check; 
}
```

**Code2:** Also doesnt work.

```
 bool SetIpAddr(string & aIpAddr)
 {
     bool lResult = false;    
     std::fstream  ifile("platform_ip_config");      
     string lTargetIp = HeadAIdValue + ExternalIpNamePostfix+ ValueAssignmentCharacter;
     std::deque<std::string>lines;
     std::string inbuf;
     while( std::getline(ifile, inbuf));
     {
         std::cout<<" we are in while"<<std::endl;
         std::cout<<" getline =="<< inbuf<< std::endl;
         std::cout<<" ip =="<<lTargetIp<< std::endl;
         if( 0 == inbuf.compare(0,lTargetIp.size(),lTargetIp) )
         {
             std::cout<<" we are in matching"<<std::endl;            
             std::cout<< inbuf << std::endl;
         inbuf.erase(inbuf.begin()+lTargetIp.size(), inbuf.end());
             std::cout<<" after erase " << inbuf << std::endl;
         inbuf.insert(0+lTargetIp.size(), aIpAddr);
             std::cout<< " after insertinon  " << inbuf << std::endl;        
         }
         lines.push_back(inbuf);
     } 
     ifile.seekg (0, ios::beg );
     std::copy(lines.begin(), lines.end(), 
     std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ifile, "\n"));
  }
  lines.push_back(inbuf);
}
ifile.seekg (0, ios::beg );
std::copy(lines.begin(), lines.end(), 
std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ifile, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: ifstream = input file stream, ofstream = output file stream. If you want both: fstream.

Comment: I have tried using fstream but in that case getline function doesnt work. I have added few debug statments to check it before posting

Comment: it doesnt allow to paste all the contents of config file. The file permission is 777 for the config file just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is inherently tricky, writing to the middle of a file hoping the result will remain in place.

for example

```
192.168.120.111
```

uses up a lot more characters than

```
10.10.10.10
```

the way i would do this is read the whole files into lines.

```
std::fstream file(file_name);
std::deque<std::string> lines;
std::string temp;
while(std::getline(file, temp))
{
    //detect that this the line you want
    if(this_is_my_line(temp)) 
    {
         //do what you need to do to the string
         modify(temp);
    }

    lines.push_back(temp);
}
file.seekg (0, ios::beg
//write back to file
std::copy(lines.begin(), lines.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(file, "\n"));
```

Please note you do not need to explicitly close a file in C++, the RAII semantics will close it for you, by doing it your self your increasing the opportunity for bugs to creep into your code.

THIS WORKS ON MY SYSTEM

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::string line;
    const std::string token("SYSTEM_A_EXTERNAL_IP=");
    std::deque<std::string> lines;
    {
        std::ifstream file("config.txt");
        while(std::getline(file, line))
        {
            if(std::equal(token.begin(), token.end(), line.begin()))
            {
                line=token+"10.10.10.5"; //or whatever
            }
            lines.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    {
        std::ofstream file("config.txt");
        std::copy(lines.begin(), lines.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(file,"\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @1111111 , I am stil facing the same problem. it goes to while statement but temp is empty inside it.

Comment: well , in my case the above function doesnt even read line from getline. I have added a debug statement after while to check  what are the contents  in the temp but it seem to be empty.  AM I DOING something wrong here?

Comment: it sounds like you are reading the wrong file or something like that

Comment: I dont think so , I have checked lot of times to make sure I am reading the correct file

Comment: can you add the exact file to your question?

Comment: the file that I am trying to modify is in same folder. Do  you want sample of config file?

Comment: @samantha the new code I have listed works on my system: it is not ideal as I have open two streams rather than one but I don't have time to play around with seeking just now.

Comment: Thanks , its working fine, I forget to change the config file name in ostream to my config file. But now  your new code is working like a charm. THanks

Comment: @samantha glad to hear it, if you can combine the streams into a single fstream then that would be a little better but the listed code is correct and robust.

Answer (score 1):

By using an ifstream you are opening the file for reading, if you use the fstream base class instead you should be able modify the file

Another approach is to read the entire file into a buffer, make changes to the buffer and overwrite the original file using the ofstream class